# Why django transaction sends double commit?

Tags: django, transactions

I'm trying to write a code that will add a new user (Django User model and Employee module). 
When calling the code, I get a Duplicate entry error. However, data have been added. 
As I try to add an existing record intentionally, Duplicate entry error appears twice.

```py
@transaction.atomic
def add(self):
   u=User(username=new_username, ... )
   emp=Employee(...)
   try:
      u.save()
      emp.save()
   except IntegrityError as e:
      print(e)
```

Comment: You've set `e` as the employee and as the exception?

Comment: @DanielHolmes sorry for my mistake, typo :(

Comment: Show us the code that calls your `add` function or more of the `add` function, because right now, the code you're showing would crash (`new_username` is not defined). It's clear the error comes from somewhere else. Maybe a full stack trace can help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
except IntegrityError as e:
    print(e)
```

to:

```
except IntegrityError as error:
    print(error)
```

Comment: It works. But why? Why was variable name a problem?